# Auteurs à propos de la beauté de la guerre

Tags: étymologie, littérature

Je cherche des auteurs qui évoqueraient la beauté de la guerre, sur les différents points de vue :

- Beauté esthétique (visuelle, auditive, ...)
- Beauté technique (art de la guerre, finesse stratégique, ...)
- Beauté conceptuelle *(?)* (buts, ...)

Je pense notamment à des citations connues comme les *quelques arpents de neige* de Voltaire qui évoque une "Belle Guerre" ou encore *Ah Dieu ! Que la guerre est jolie* (**Calligrammes**, Apollinaire).

J'étais aussi intéressé par l'aspect étymologique : en latin `bellum` se rapproche étrangement de `bellus` et je me demandais si il y avait historiquement un quelconque rapport entre ces deux termes.

Comment: La guerre nous a volé Apollinaire qui était le plus grand de tous. Ne serait-ce que pour cela, elle a perdu, à tout jamais, toute prétention à la beauté.

Comment: @RomainVALERI : D'où ma question, notamment sur le vers issus de Calligrammes

Comment: Je pense au [_Dormeur du Val_](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Dormeur_du_val) de Rimbaud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cela traverse il me semble toutes les représentations artistiques de la guerre, soit explicitement, soit implicitement (et contre les intentions affichées de leur auteur). Plus ou moins brièvement, et en vrac:

Les poèmes de jeunesse de **Drieu la Rochelle** illustrent par exemple cela (*Fonds de cantine*, *État-civil*), à comparer avec sa désillusion rétrospective de *La Comédie de Charleroi*.

Pour ce qui est de l'aspect cosmique de la guerre (au sens antique où ce qui participait de l'ordre du monde serait nécessairement beau), on trouve cette survivance chez des auteurs comme **Ernst Jünger** ; je pense à *Orages d'acier* ou à son essai *La Guerre comme expérience intérieure*. Vous avez aussi celui qui est un peu son homologue français, même s'il est moins talentueux et plus virulent, René Quinton (*Maximes sur la guerre*), qui se place dans une perspective darwininienne en disant avec Joseph de Maistre [(*Considérations sur la France*)](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0GEaAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA39&ots=4ekDd55vxm&dq=maistre%20arbre%20humain%20sang&hl=fr&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q&f=false) que

> Ce qu'on voit assez clairement, c'est que le genre humain peut être
> considéré comme un arbre qu'une main invisible taille sans relâche et
> qui gagne souvent à cette opération.

et qu'

> En un mot, on dirait que le sang est l'engrais de cette plante qu'on
> appelle *génie*.

Vous pouvez aussi remonter à une des sources antiques de cela, même si cela vous éloigne de votre perspective esthétique, et voir dans le *[Lachès](http://remacle.org/bloodwolf/philosophes/platon/cousin/laches.htm#182c)* de **Platon** (trad. V. Cousin) qu'

> il est certain qu'il est beau et utile d'apprendre tout ce qui regarde
> le métier de la guerre, et d'acquérir les connaissances auxquelles ces
> exercices servent de préludes.

Ici, la beauté est une beauté classique, c'est celle du *kalos kagathos* (bel et bon), pour lequel le devoir et ce qui permet de l'accomplir ne saurait être que beau alors qu'à l'époque moderne, la célébration des beautés de la guerre relève plus du *Sturm und Drang* romantique.

Et puis il y a, du côté du premier de nos poètes, **Homère**, une évocation par le fait de cette beauté de la guerre — car qu'est-ce l'*Illiade* sinon le récit magnifique d'une suite de combats, et qu'est-ce d'autre que la littérature (et le cinéma) de guerre que la continuation parfois schizophrène de ce projet, qui pour condamner la guerre en donne la représentation la plus sublime ou la plus atroce, en un mot, la plus *belle* ?
Ainsi du *lamento* de Priam face à son fils Hector (voir surtout le dernier paragraphe, mais j'ai quelque scrupule à couper plus):

> Hector, mon enfant, n'attends pas cet homme, tout seul, loin des
> autres, de peur que bientôt tu n'atteignes le moment fatal, dompté par
> le fils de Pelée, car il est bien plus fort que toi, le misérable ! Ah
> ! puisse-t-il devenir aussi cher aux dieux qu'il l'est à moi-même !
>
> Bientôt alors les chiens et les vautours le dévoreraient, étendu dans
> la plaine, et une affreuse douleur quitterait mes entrailles. C'est
> lui qui m'a privé de tant de vaillants fils, les tuant ou les vendant
> en des îles lointaines. […]
>
> De plus, prends pitié de moi. de cet infortuné qui garde encore sa
> présence d'esprit, de ce malheureux que le Père, fils de Cronos, va
> faire périr en un triste destin au seuil de la vieillesse, après
> l'avoir soumis à des maux
> innombrables. Il aura vu ses fils exterminés, ses filles entraînées,
> ses appartements dévastés, ses petits-enfants jetés contre terre dans
> un carnage atroce, et ses brus tiraillées par les mains pernicieuses
> des Achéens.
>
> Et moi-même enfin, le dernier de tous, les chiens carnassiers me
> déchireront sur le seuil de ma porte, lorsqu'un ennemi, m'ayant blessé
> de près avec le bronze aigu ou bien frappé de loin, se rendra maître
> de la vie de mes membres ; et ces chiens que j'avais à ma table
> nourris en mon palais pour qu'ils gardent mes portes, ces chiens,
> quand ils auront bu mon sang, le cœur empli de rage, resteront
> allongés dans mon vestibule. À un jeune guerrier, tué par Arès,
> déchiré par le bronze acéré, il convient sans réserve de rester
> étendu. Jusque dans la mort, tout en lui reste beau, quoi qu'il laisse
> apparaître. Mais quand les chiens outragent la tête grise, le menton
> gris et les parties honteuses d'un vieillard massacré, c'est
> assurément là le spectacle le plus pitoyable qui puisse s'offrir aux
> malheureux mortels.
>
> [ Homère, l'*Illiade*, [chant XXII](http://iliadeodyssee.texte.free.fr/aatexte/meunier/iliadmeunier/iliadmeunier22/iliadmeunier22.htm), trad. Meunier. ]

Ce passage n'est pas sans évoquer un auteur très contemporain, Chuck Palahniuk, qui dans Fight Club, fait dire à un de ses personnages:

> I wanted to destroy something beautiful

De là, pour en revenir encore à quelque chose de plus réflexif, la psychanalyse (la pulsion de mort, *thanatos*) ou **Georges Bataille** (*La Part maudite*) auront des choses à dire à cette enseigne.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse !